# Native Message received, but response failed

Tags: c++, macos, google-chrome, chrome-native-messaging

I am developing a macOS application which can communicate with google chrome extension through `native messaging`.

I used google official documentation from [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging), so I received data from extension successfully (as is shown in below).

But when I tried to answer, I always get an error. 
My response is in JSON format and it is:

```
{
 "text":
        "Client Started"
}
```

I use `swift` for my `viewController` and `Objective-c++` for native messaging:

ViewController.swift:

```
let stream = StreamReader()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    stream.getStream()
    stream.writeStream("{\"text\":\"Client Started\"}")
}
```

StreamReader.m:

```
- (void)WriteStream:(NSString *)JSONResponse {
    NSString *JSONResponseArray = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", JSONResponse];
    std::string outMsg = [JSONResponseArray UTF8String];
    unsigned int len = outMsg.length();
    std::cout.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&len), 4);
    std::cout << outMsg.data() << std::flush;
}
```

Error:

[image]

**Notice**: I tried to change both response and its length, but the error is same in both situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should output the string's length info to stdout:

```
    unsigned int len = outMsg.length();
    std::cout<< char(len & 0xFF)
             << char(((len >> 8) & 0xFF))
             << char(((len >> 16) & 0xFF))
             << char(((len >> 24) & 0xFF));
```

Now you can write the string data to stdout.

Then use [std::flush](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush) to immediately flush the data i.e. send the data from our native messaging host to destination extension. I have noticed that if we won't do so then this data won't be sent to the destination immediately.

```
std::cout << outMsg.data() << std::flush;
```

Comment: Thank you. It really helped me.