# Can a native application initiate communication via Chrome's NativeMessaging API?

Tags: google-chrome, native, chromium, messaging, chrome-native-messaging

I'm trying to understand if a NodeJS application can initiate communication with Chrome via `NativeMessaging`, or if it can only reply to messages which originate from Chrome. The documentation is rather lacking in this regard.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging

If this is possible, how can a native application initiate such a message?

Comment: You can reply to or send messages which originate from Chrome and Chrome extensions too. Here's how you can send messages from native messaging host to Chrome extension but it's in C++: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46301554/native-message-received-but-response-failed

Comment: @Asesh thanks for your reply. Can you clarify though, can my application INITIATE communication with Chrome? If so, how?

Comment: You can initiate communication with Chrome. You will have to add a listener which will listen for messages from your native messaging host.

Comment: Thanks @Asesh, but in all the documentation I don't see any way to initiate messages from the host and listen in Chrome. I only see the possibility to listen in the native host and initiate from Chrome. Is there any specific resource you've found regarding this?