# Why doesnt' native app show up until Chrome closed when nativemessage sent?

Tags: c#, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I have an extension that messaging native application in Chrome. When I send a message native app doesn't shown until chrome is closed. What is the problem here?

```
chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener(function(item, suggest) {

valpairs = item.finalUrl + "e7dfa9a6-f9d8-4146-89f5-ca441f0f5b23" + valpairs;

var port = chrome.runtime.connectNative('com.alto.downloadmanager');
port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
  console.log("Received" + msg);
});
port.onDisconnect.addListener(function() {
  console.log("Disconnected");
});
port.postMessage({ text: valpairs });


chrome.downloads.cancel(item.id);
});
```

**Program.cs:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            JObject data;
            var processed = "";
            while ((data = Read()) != null)
            {
                processed = ProcessMessage(data);
                Write(processed);
                if (processed == "exit")
                {
                    break;
                }
            }


            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1(processed));

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to flush that data to immediately send it to your native messaging host. It's not clear from your post, what API you are using for writing to standard input. If you are using `FileStream` then use [FileStream.Flush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.flush?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamWriter_Flush) or if you are using `StreamWriter` then use [StreamWriter.Flush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.flush?view=netframework-4.8) and `std::flush` in [C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush) as I have mentioned in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46301554/native-message-received-but-response-failed/46303688#46303688)