# Strange behaviour when sending messages from c++ to chromium extension [Native Messaging] - No data being sent

Tags: c++, chrome-native-messaging

Hi and hope everyone is doing good!

I started working on a chrome extension which talks to a cpp exe. At the moment I am just trying to read some data from the extension which works as expected using the following code

```
unsigned int length = 0;

{
    unsigned int read_char = getchar();
    length = length | (read_char << index*8);
}

std::string message = "";
for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
{
    message += getchar();
}
```

When trying to send the same information from the cpp -> extension using the following code

```
unsigned int len = message.length();


printf("%c%c%c%c",  (char) (len & 0xff),
                    (char) (len << 8 & 0xff),
                    (char) (len << 16 & 0xff),
                    (char) (len << 24 & 0xff));


printf("%s", message.c_str());
```

it works as expected
[Screenshot of the working scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIjaN.png)

However, when i try to send back another string rather than the same string that we send it won't work.
Example:

```
    unsigned int length = 0;


for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++)
{
    unsigned int read_char = getchar();
    cerr << read_char << endl;
    length = length | (read_char << index*8);
}

std::string message = "";
for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
{
    message += getchar();
}

std::string outputMessage = "output";

unsigned int len = outputMessage.length();


printf("%c%c%c%c",  (char) (len & 0xff),
                    (char) (len << 8 & 0xff),
                    (char) (len << 16 & 0xff),
                    (char) (len << 24 & 0xff));


printf("%s", outputMessage.c_str());



return 0;
```

Here is also the screenshot of the scenario that **is failing.** [Failed scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myrvE.png)

---

I am not sure what I missed here, consider that I am just creating a new string and also using it's length for information that the extension needs.

Anyway, it would be great if anyone could look at this one. Thanks in advance :)

UPDATE:
After trying different ways of returning messages I found this on the web and it works as expected

```
message_t encode_message(json content) {
    string encoded_content = content.dump();
    message_t m;
    m.content = encoded_content;
    m.length = (uint32_t)encoded_content.length();
    return m;
}

// Send an encoded message to stdout.
void send_message(message_t encoded_message) {
    char* raw_length = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&encoded_message.length);
    fwrite(raw_length, 4, sizeof(char), stdout);
    fwrite(encoded_message.content.c_str(), encoded_message.length, sizeof(char), stdout);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly flush the buffer, if those data are to be sent to the native messaging host ASAP as shown below:

```
std::string outputMessage = "output";

unsigned int len = outputMessage.length();

printf("%c%c%c%c", (char) (len & 0xff),
                   (char) ((len >> 8) & 0xff),
                   (char) ((len >> 16) & 0xff),
                   (char) ((len >> 24) & 0xff));


printf("%s", outputMessage.c_str());
fflush(stdout); // This will flush the buffer
```

Comment: Thanks @Asesh for your answer, but I tried adding that and still the same behavior on the extension, no message received :(

Comment: Did you check your listener? Put a break point or logging in your listener and check if it got the message. We have been doing that in our native messaging host app and it works

Comment: Hi Asesh, yeah I've checked the response but looked like the issue was on the C++ (I still don't know why. Anyways, I tried another example on the web and it worked!

Comment: @defrimhsn Just noticed it, you are using left-shift rather than using right-shift. I have answered similar question here but by using `std::cout`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46301554/native-message-received-but-response-failed/46303688#46303688

Comment: Darn! Thanks @asesh.